# Shiny R histogram not changing with slider

Tags: r, shiny, dataset, slider, histogram

I am trying to create an histogram using shiny on my [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/chocolate-bar-ratings). I would like to be able to use a slider on it in order to change the number of histograms.
My dataset has a column (cocoa percentage) with values in [50, 100]. After making it numeric instead of categorical, I would use the histogram to see the frequence of 50, 51, ... or the frequence of 50-55, 56-60, ...
I wrote this code, but nothing happens when I run it. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me make it work please?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Chocolate Bar Ratings"),

        # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 1)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(chocolate$CocoaPerc, xlab="Percentuale di cacao", main="Frequenza della percentuale
di cacao", col = c("chocolate", "chocolate3", "chocolate2", "chocolate4"))

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example we don't own the Chocolate dataset, look into the dput function

Comment: Sorry, I'm adding the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `input$bins` was not used in the `output$distPlot` function see the `# <---`comment. Note also that I just invented a random data set:

```
library(shiny)

chocolate <- data.frame(CocoaPerc=runif(100, min=0, max=99))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Chocolate Bar Ratings"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 1)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(chocolate$CocoaPerc, 
         nclass = input$bins, # <---
         xlab="Percentuale di cacao", 
         main="Frequenza della percentuale di cacao", 
         col = c("chocolate", "chocolate3", "chocolate2", "chocolate4"))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Edit: I edited the post and removed the reference to the unused faithful data set. To adapt the chocolate colors into an increasing scale is just another question. You may look for `colorRampPalette`.

Comment: Do you also know how to make two plots fit in the screen? by copying and pasting your code twice, one histogram goes very down in the page, while the rest the sliders and the other one remain on top

Comment: You can simply use `par(mfrow ....)`  for base graphics plots. For the others, e.g. lattice, ggplot, plotly or dygraphs you will find many other examples on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much again! :)